# Read csv file excluding first column and first line

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file containing 8 lines and 1777 columns.

I need to read all the contents in matlab, excluding the first line and first column. First line and first column contain strings and matlab can't parse them.

Do you have any idea?

```
 data = csvread(filepath);
```

The code above reads all the contents

Comment: You can set what you want to read in the csvread command:
`M = csvread(filename,row,col,csvRange)`. Check the help for it, an example of what you want to do is provided there.

In your case `data = csvread(filepath,1,1);` should do it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, csvread with a range will read in the numeric data.  If you would like to read in the strings as well (which are presumably column headers), you can use readtable:

```
t = readtable(filepath);
```

This will create a table with the column headers in your file as variable names of the columns of the table.  This way you can keep the strings associated with the data, if need be.